# Gradle throw NoSuchFileException for existing file on Ubuntu

Tags: java, unix, gradle, spock

I'm working on a small Gradle project and want to use my `Reader` class in a Spock test. When I start the test the `Reader` class throws:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException
```

In my Gradle project, I have `test.txt` file in `/src/test/resources`. When I run the test with my `Reader` then Gradle shows me:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: file:project_path/build/resources/test/test.txt
```

even though there is a file in that path. I checked using both the terminal and the browser.

I use Java 11 on Ubuntu.

```
//Reader class read lines:    
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Path.of(String.valueOf(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName)))))

//gradle.build without test dependencies
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "groovy"

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0"
sourceCompatibility = "1.11"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Reader` read logic on:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Path.of(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(fileName).toURI()))) {
    ...
}
```

`Path.of()` will create correct path when using URI: */project_path/build/resources/test/test.txt* because it will extract path from the provider specified by the protocol in the URI (*file:* in your case).

But when you call `Path.of()` for `String` argument it assumes it is the real path (*file:project_path/build/resources/test/test.txt* in your case).